# replace namespace uri using XSLT in SOAP message

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt, xslt-grouping

**i have an input soap message, trying to replace part of namespace uri with a different string. I am able to replace entire URI with a different URI, but not able to modify the existing URI. I need to look for 'OLDSTRING' and replace with 'NEWSTRING'. The string VARIABLESTRING varies in in every input xml, so I should keep as it is in the output xml**

Input XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
            <merchantID>TESTID</merchantID>   
          </requestMessage>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**OUTPUT XML:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-NEWSTRING-com:transaction-data-1.69">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-NEWSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
        <merchantID>TESTID</merchantID>   
      </requestMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried the following XSL, and able to change the namespace URI, but i want to replace only 'OLDSTRING' with 'NEWSTRING' and keep remaining string as it is.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//*[namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:schemas-NEWSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This kind of processing is easy in XSLT 2.0, but quite tricky in XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTarget" select="'OLDSTRING'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pRepl" select="'NEWSTRING'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[starts-with(namespace-uri(), 'urn:schemas')
   or
     namespace::*[starts-with(., 'urn:schemas')]
    ]">

  <xsl:variable name="vNS" select="namespace-uri()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vNewNS">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($vNS, $pTarget))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vNS"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($vNS, $pTarget)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pRepl"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($vNS, $pTarget)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNewNS}">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
     "namespace::*
        [not(. = $vNS
            or
             starts-with(., 'urn:schemas')
           and
             contains(., $pTarget)
             )
        ]"/>

   <xsl:for-each select=
     "namespace::*
        [starts-with(., 'urn:schemas')
       and
         contains(., $pTarget)
        ]">
     <xsl:variable name="vNewNSUri" select=
     "concat(substring-before(., $pTarget),
             $pRepl,
             substring-after(., $pTarget)
             )
     "/>

     <xsl:variable name="vPrefix" select="name()"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vPref">
       <xsl:if test="$vPrefix">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat($vPrefix, ':')"/>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vrtfDoc">
      <xsl:element name="{$vPref}dummy"
                   namespace="{$vNewNSUri}"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "ext:node-set($vrtfDoc)/*/namespace::*[. = $vNewNSUri]"/>
   </xsl:for-each>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
            <merchantID>TESTID</merchantID>
        </requestMessage>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-NEWSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-NEWSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING">
      <merchantID>TESTID</merchantID>
    </requestMessage>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//*[namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-OLDSTRING-com:VARIABLESTRING']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{replace(namespace-uri(), 'OLDSTRING', 'NEWSTRING')}" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No, there is no `replace()` function in XPath 1.0/XSLT 1.0. It is a good idea to test the code before publishing it.